# Display updated text on screen in lua

Tags: lua, gideros

I am using Lua with gideros
I have the text updating in OnEnterFrame method:

```
count = count + 1
text7 = TextField.new(conf.fontchange, count)
text7:setPosition(conf.dx - conf.width/3, conf.dy - conf.height/3)
text7:setTextColor(0x000ff)
self:addChild(text7)
```

but this way the next count is just displayed over the earlier one.

If I do

`self:removeChild(text7)` , the text is not displayed at all. Where should I be removing the last count so that only the updated count is displayed?

Comment: Where did you try putting the `removeChild`, please show in code.

Comment: @Schollii : I just needed to used setText instead of removing the child.Fixed now :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
text7 = TextField.new(conf.fontchange, count)
text7:setPosition(conf.dx - conf.width/3, conf.dy - conf.height/3)
text7:setTextColor(0x000ff)
self:addChild(text7)
```

And then later inside `ENTER_FRAME` event:

```
count = count + 1
text7:setText(count)
```